# Riddle Number Seven

Tags: riddle, cipher

[image]

Seems as if I've left you all a little puzzle for today. It's a simple cipher that I'm sure you can all deduce. Everything you need is provided in the image. Have fun everyone!

Comment: Could you use a little more descriptive naming scheme for your puzzles, please and thank you.

Comment: How so? These are but riddles, entwined in an enigma, wrapped in a mystery ;)

Comment: maybe add visual tag as well?

Answer (score 1):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**

**Decryption Method**

> Reading upside down, the bottom of the image shows "vigenere", and upright bottom left, "Cipher". Therefore, we may need to use **Vigenere Cipher**, with the key, according to the top right corner, "**riddle 6 answer**" (which, sadly, has not been solved... :( )(credits to @Dorrulf)

**Other Words**

> middle, upside down: bald 
>  middle, upside down, in triangle: uxye

**"Reflect On This" Box**

> Maybe put a mirror there? But that doesn't work; I tried it. Maybe the inverted question marks in the box vs the big two outside the box on two sides are hints?

**SUSPICIOUS STUFF I HAVE NOT FIGURED OUT**

> 1. The outwards arrow on the C in Cipher
>  2. The scribbling on the key
> 3. The 3 dots under 'w'　above the big ? on the right

Comment: I believe it actually says the answer to riddle six is the key for this one.

Comment: Good eye Dorrulf ;) As for Omega, the path is simple, yet may seem vague ;)

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

> Here is the image flipped vertically and horizontally. I believe much of the encoded text should be read in this manner.
>  [image: flipped puzzle image]

Comment: There's a reason I did what I did haha

Comment: I guess a lot of it could be read both ways with different outcomes. I guess I should've stated this is a possible perspective for some of the words.

Comment: Here's a hint I'll provide. My hint is that I reflected this riddle in my own way, but most of it is in the correct order. As for the word bald, a coincidence.